# Java setting class variables back to defaults

Tags: java

In Java, if I have a class such as:

```
public class Example {

  private String s;
  private int i;

  public Example() {
  }

  // set variables back to default initializations
  public clear() {

     // how?
  }


}
```

When this class is instantiated, my understanding is that `s` and `i` would be set to `null` and `0`, respectively.

Is there a way to define a clear method so that it sets all class variables back to their defaults?

I realize it might not be best practice to rely on the default values, but I have code with hundreds of such variables (all Strings and ints). Seems redundant to define clear methods and initializations when the defaults happen to be what I need.

Comment: What you are going to achieve with that?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know what the default values are, you just manually assign it.

`int` is 0, objects are `null` and so on.. (See the [JLS - 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for details)

But the question is, why would you want to do that instead of simply creating new instance?

Comment: The author of these classes has done that for now, i.e. manually set to 0 and null within the clear method.  I suppose I could modify the code using the class to create a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a clear method, just re instantiate the class:

```
Example example = new Example();
example.doSomething();
example = new Example(); //this will reset the variable's values to their default
```

Comment: No. It just won't reset the values to default but it will also create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Example example = new Example();
example.doSomeWork();
example = new Example(); //??
```

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Have something like below:

```
public class Example {

  private String s;
  private int i;

  public Example() {
     this.clear();
  }

  // set variables back to default initializations
  public clear() {
     // call this method from within constructor and whenever you would like to reset
     s = new String("abc"); // example initializer, actually re-assignment
     i = 0; // presuming this is the default initilization
  }
}
```